# How to replace a Default List "Events" with a new custom list for all the sites

Tags: 2007, development, feature, custom-list

I am trying to find a script that will replace Sharepoint Events List with one of Custom List i created + Copy all the data of Events list to my newly created list.

I know how to Delete a list and Create a new list, but dunno if there is any simplest way of replacing a Moss List.

Cheers

Comment: Why do you want to replace the list? If the existing list has information in it you have the risk of links to the existing list.  In a lot of cases create a new Content Type add that content type to the list and change all the existing items will be a better solution

Comment: I hidden Meeting Workspace checkbox from the list and created a new list based on that schema, but because its a big organization i am working for and my senior Developer asked me to do it this way, so i have to follow him :/, even tho i know some quick fixes like changing the scheme file in the 12 hive on live servers, But again am not allowed and suppose to follow the instructions, Cheers

Comment: Changing a list schema in the 12 hive is absolutely NOT a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Approach I used to Solve the Issue is,

- Create a New List
- Copy Items to New List
- Delete old List

//Add a List

```
web.Lists.Add(listName, listDesc, t);
```

//Copying

```
SPList myDestinationList = web.Lists[destinationlistName];
                SPList mySourceList = web.Lists[Form1.OldListName];
                SPQuery mySourceListQuery = new SPQuery();
 SPQuery mySourceListQuery = new SPQuery();

            mySourceListQuery.Query = "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Title' /><FieldRef Name='Location' /></OrderBy>";" 
            SPListItemCollection mySourceItemColl = mySourceList.GetItems(mySourceListQuery);
            foreach (SPListItem mySourceListItem in mySourceItemColl)
            {
                SPListItem myDestinationListItem = myDestinationList.Items.Add();

                if (mySourceListItem["Title"] != null)
                    myDestinationListItem["Title"] = mySourceListItem["Title"];

                if (mySourceListItem["Location"] != null)
                    myDestinationListItem["Location"] = mySourceListItem["Location"];


                web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                myDestinationListItem.Update();
                web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
```

//deleting a list

```
        web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
        SPList myList = web.Lists[list];
        myList.Delete();
        web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
```